# Get Posts by IDs (optionally)

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, loop

I want to check if a variable contains list of post IDs, then I want to query the posts of those IDs only, but if that variable is empty then I want to display all posts.

Problem:
If I supply IDs to `post__in`, then it gets the posts with those IDs, but if it is empty then it should return **all posts** but it returns no any post.

For example, the following code will get the posts with IDs 1,2,3. However this will return no any post if the $`ids` is empty. Shouldn't it return ALL posts in that case? How can I get all posts if `$ids` is empty ie. `$ids = "";` ?

```
$ids = '1,2,3';
$arr = explode("," ,$ids);

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $number,    
    'post__in' => $arr, 
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if it is empty"? How do you check emptiness? WordPress should ignore `post__in` param if it's really empty - `$q['post__in'] == false`.

Comment: I meant if `$ids = '';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like WordPress doesn't ignore empty `post__in` param. So you'll have to do this yourself like this...

```
$ids = '1,2,3';

if ( $ids ) {
    $arr = explode("," ,$ids);

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $number,    
        'post__in' => $arr
    );
} else {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $number
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Krysiek's answer. They both should accomplish the same thing and only add the `post__in` parameter if the $ids exist.

```
$ids = '1,2,3';
$arr = explode("," ,$ids);

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $number,    
);

if( $ids )
   $args['post__in'] = $arr;
```